# How do you deal with a user who is constantly downvoting perfectly reasonable answers?

Tags: discussion

My current approach has been to upvote to counteract the downvote, but it would be nice if there were a better solution.

Related questions: In what venue is it appropriate to approach a user about their behavior? Is this part of a moderator's job?

Comment: ...if that user does not leave proper premises for downvotes, it is bad. I like users that can handle both negative and positive comments. I often down/up-vote but I like to leave there a premise for my action. If my action is baseless, I will re-evaluate it later. Negative votes are essential to kill spam. Why should this site live in euphoria?  I think it is more problem that some users do not state their reasons for down-votes -- revenge mentality does not help anyone. And I am commenting because I know I get odd downvotes in this site time-to-time.

Comment: How do you know who to approach?

Comment: How do you know it is a particular user?

Comment: I rarely downvote answers, but have done it on a few occasions.  Generally I either comment, or upvote an existing comment that explains why it's a bad answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend flagging the relevant posts for moderator attention, so the moderators can look into it.